using RunnablePassthrough() on promt template LangChain JS
I've been learning couple weeks how to use Langchain and I started to follow the tutorial that they show on their website https://js.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/expression_language/cookbook/retrieval/
and now I'm trying to adapt it to my project but I'm having problem trying to pass a variable to my prompts, I saw that you can do this using the  RunnablePassthrough() method when you invoke the chain but I don't know what I'm doing wrong at the moment that I use it...
I have two prompts, one for getting the standalone questions for the llm and give it to the retriever and the second where the llm generates the answer
`const customerAssistancePrompt = `Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question.

Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:`;

const answerTemplate = ` ''prompt''

chat History:
{chat_history}

context that has customer information and policies:
{context}

last line:
 {question}

your answer:
`;`

these are my Chains for the RunnableSequence method:
 ` const standaloneQuestionChain = RunnableSequence.from([
    {
      question: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) => input.question,
      chat_history: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) =>
        formatChatHistory(input.chat_history),
    },
    CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    llm,
    new StringOutputParser(),
  ]);

  const answerChain = RunnableSequence.from([
    {
      context: retrieveDocuments,
      question: new RunnablePassthrough(),
      chat_history: new RunnablePassthrough(),
    },
    ANSWER_PROMPT,
    llm,
    new StringOutputParser(),
  ]);
`

but at the moment I try to pass the chat_history to the second prompt it gives me an error that this variable is missing, this is how I try to invoke it:
 `const answerQAChain = RunnableSequence.from([
    {
      question: standaloneQuestionChain,
      original_input: new RunnablePassthrough(),
    },
    {
      context: retrieveDocuments,
      question: ({ original_input }) => original_input.question,
      chat_history: ({ original_input }) => original_input.chat_history,
    },
    answerChain,
  ]);
`

maybe its a dumb error that I'm making but actually I have not get any way for making it works...
this is the error:
 ⨯ Error: Missing value for input chat_history
